# Loop a file search continuously

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm new to visual basic and am trying to make a console application that searches for PDF files in a directory and then opens the most recently created file. I'd like the search to run automatically from when the program is opened to when it is closed.

So far I've been able to search the folder and open the file, but I'm not sure how to make the search continuous.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Diagnostics.Process

Module Module1
    Dim SearchDir As String
    Dim OldestFile As FileInfo = Nothing
    Dim NewestFile As FileInfo = Nothing
    Dim OpenFile As String = Nothing
    Dim FileCount As Integer = 0

Sub Main()
    SearchDir = "C:\Reports"
    Dim Directory As New DirectoryInfo(SearchDir)

    Console.WriteLine("Searching {0}", SearchDir)
    Console.WriteLine()
    Try
        For Each finfo In Directory.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            If OldestFile Is Nothing OrElse finfo.LastWriteTime <= OldestFile.LastWriteTime Then
                OldestFile = finfo
            End If

            If NewestFile Is Nothing OrElse finfo.LastWriteTime >= NewestFile.LastWriteTime Then
                NewestFile = finfo
            End If

            FileCount += 1
        Next


        Console.WriteLine("Oldest file is {0} {1}.", OldestFile.LastWriteTime, OldestFile.Name)
        Console.WriteLine("Newest file is {0} {1}.", NewestFile.LastWriteTime, NewestFile.Name)

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("{0} files searched", FileCount)



        Try

            Dim APP = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\acrord32.exe", vbMaximizedFocus)
            Thread.Sleep(5000) 'Delay 5 seconds for program initialize
            Dim reader As Process
            reader = Process.Start(NewestFile.FullName)

            Thread.Sleep(2000) 'Delay 2 seconds for program initialize
            SendKeys.SendWait("^l")
            Thread.Sleep(2000) 'Delay 2 seconds for program initialize
            SendKeys.SendWait("^+h")

        Catch ex2 As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR Activating Adobe Reader.")
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Try
```

Comment: You don't make the search continuous. You search just one time, then prepare a FileSystemWatcher instance and ask it to notify you when a new PDF file is added to the folder.

Comment: Per Steve's comment, a FileSystemWatcher is what you want. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx